# Set the fonts toa text in android

Tags: android

Hi want to change the font type to atext according to spinner selection like arial balck,Thlist etc.any one have idea ? suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the typefaces of your text views. You can specify a variable:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT;
```

Then when the user chooses another font you reinitialize this variable, using the built-in typefaces, or loading your own from `.ttf` files, that you can place in `assets/fonts` directory. Loading own fonts can be done with this call:

```
typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/font.ttf");
```

This should do it.